# What's the best fit SSD for the Acer Aspire 1420p laptop?

Tags: laptop, ssd

I have an [Acer Aspire 1420P notebook](http://support.acer.com/acerpanam/notebook/2009/acer/aspire/Aspire1420P/Aspire1420Psp2.shtml). I'm considering buying an SSD for it, but having trouble figuring out what types of SSD are supported by it.

Specifically, I'm looking for two answers:

1. What SSD architecture, MLC or SLC, will work with the laptop?
2. What interface type, PATA, SATA, SATA II, SATA III, etc. will work with it?

or a link to a document explaining all these concepts will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it really matters what goes on behind the scenes.  I'm pretty sure that it uses SATA, and SATA II and SATA III should both work on SATA anyway.  They just have speed increases for ports that support SATA II and SATA III.

PATA is super ghetto old so I doubt that your laptop uses PATA.  Almost everything is SATA. Open up your laptop and see for yourself if you like.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. What about MLC vs. SLC? Does it matter either?

Comment: See this: http://www.overclock.net/hard-drives-storage/495634-ssd-mlc-vs-slc.html  For compatability, I don't think that it matters, but it seems that SLC is faster and MLC has a higher capacity.  SLC vs MLC is an internal thing.

Answer (score 2):

Does SLC/MLC matter?
No, it doesn't. Just make sure you are getting the right form factor (2.5') and interface.

Comment: Good point, I forgot to mention the form factor.